# How to check if a file is empty in VERILOG?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to know how can I check if a file is empty in a VERILOG or SYSTEMVERILOG testbench.

I have 2 ideas:

1. Check the file size using `$system()` task, and put there a linux command which can tell the number of bits or bytes.
2. Read the first line using `$fgets`. If the line equal to 0, it means it's empty.

About the first method, I couldn't get a linux command which tells me just the number.  I've tried for example `ls -l` and `wc -c`, but they give me much more than the number of bits.

About the second method, I really don't know how to read a specific line, in this case, it would be the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already checked the result from `$fopen` to see if the file exists, you can use `$getc` or `$gets` an see if it returns a code less than 1. But the best option depends on what you plan to do with the file after finding it empty or non empty.